# C++ Insert character in a string

Tags: string, insert

I would like to insert some character after each number of my string 
I found how to insert before each character, but what I want is :

string str = "12 + 5"

insert ^ after each number

Output = "12^ + 5^"

Thank you for your help

Comment: Provide complete code, provide what you tried

Comment: I searched for like 1h30 and I didn't found a solution. All the topic and documentation are about inserting something at a specificate position. I want to add my character after every number. So I don't have any code, sorry. I know it's like "do it for me", but if you can show me the way, it would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
int main()
{
 char string[128] = "12 + 5";
 char output[128] = {};
 char side_string[128] = {};
 int pos_string = 0;

 for (pos_string = 0; pos < length(string); pos_string ++) {
  if (string[pos_string] < '0'  && string[pos_string] > '9') {
   if (strlen(side_string) >  0) {
    strcat(output, side_string);
    strcat(output, "^");
    side_string[0] = 0;
   }
   output[strlen(output)] = string[pos_string];
  } else {
   side_string[strlen(side_string)] = string[pos_string];
  }
 }
 if (strlen(side_string) > 0) {
  strcat(output, side_string);
  strcat(output, "^");
  side_string[0] = 0;
 }
```

NOTE:

1. The code is inefficient, but it is written for simplicity rather than briefness
2. The code is **INSECURE** there is no length checking and no validation of BO